# Crash when casting due to support library

Tags: android, android-support-library, chromecast

In My project I am using the following versions of libraries.

> Support Library - 27.1.1
>
> Google Play Services - 15.0.1
>
> Play-services-cast-framework - 15.0.1
>
> Mediarouter-v7 - 27.1.1

A class in cast-service-framework 'VideoCastNotificationService' (package : com.google.android.libraries.cast.companionlibrary.notification)  uses 'NotificationCompat' (package : android.support.v7.app.NotificationCompat) for the notification service.

```
NotificationCompat.Builder builder = (NotificationCompat.Builder) new NotificationCompat.Builder(this);
```

But, this constructor has been deprecated in support library version 26.0.0 and removed in version 27.0.0. New contructor has one more parameter along with context, ie Channel id.

So, when trying to cast, app crashes with the below log,

> Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: Didn't find class
>   "android.support.v7.app.NotificationCompat$Builder"
>   java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: Failed resolution of:
>   Landroid/support/v7/app/NotificationCompat$Builder;
>           at com.google.android.libraries.cast.companionlibrary.notification.VideoCastNotificationService.build(VideoCastNotificationService.java:338)

I have to use the latest versions of support library and target sdks to support latest Android versions. From the latest cast-service-framework also, it calls the deprecated 'NotificationCompat' contructor which results in a crash.

Can anyone help to resolve this issue?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found what the issue was, 
com.google.android.libraries.cast.companionlibrary.notification.VideoCastNotificationService.build

this is from the CCL(Cast Companion Library), which was still a part of the project, it was a legacy project.

Answer (score 0):

Change your import from `v7` to `v4` as follows,

`import android.support.v4.app.NotificationCompat;`.